# What is the purpose of adding EmailSender in infrastructure layer in clean architecture if I cannot reuse it?

Tags: .net, .net-core, architecture, .net-5, clean-architecture

Currently, I have an application that is built according to the clean architecture.

```
Project.Core
Project.Infrastructure
Project.Api
```

Inside my `Project.Core` I have defined the interface `IEmailSender` and implemented it in`EmailSender` in the `Project.Infrastructure`. I believe this is the correct way to implement the external services per the, [clean architecture documentation of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture). This works perfectly with my application.

I have a requirement to implement an email verification for the users when they register for the application. All the identity related(Login, Logout, Register) is handled in a separate project called `Project.identityServer` in the same solution. I am confused that it might violate the DRY design principle if I duplicate it in both projects.

Should I create another classLibrary for common modules? If yes, what is the purpose of implementing external services in `Infrastructure`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use interfaces to be able to change implementations without modifiying your code.

If in a future you use another "way" of sending mails, you just need to change the `IMailSender` implementation and that's all. Otherwise you would need to refactor all your code depending on your `MailSender` implementation.

Normally you would use your `IMailSender` interface also in your validation project. So yes, this intertface should reside in a common library, which will be referenced by both libraries.

Then you will inject (normally via IoC) the implementation in your services, which depend on `IMailSender`

Usually your Infrastructure library will have have the implementations of your interfaces (some of them may be declared in your "core" library and others...) which will be injected in the classes using it.

So the "infrastructure library" is a way to abstract you implementations, so your code soes not rely on specific classes but on interfaces, being way easier to refactor/change in a future.

There are some other points (it also depends if you are using DDD etc..here every Domain has its own infrastructure) but for me this is the main "reason" of an infrastructure layer.

In this case I would not duplicate the interface, as long as you need the same functionality in both libraries. If not the case, then create two interfaces, each serving the specific needs.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Rafa. But still referencing the common library will create a dependancy at the low level. Therefore, it will not be a clean architecture after all

Comment: No...In your case you declare `IMailSender` in your core project (if your core classes needs to send the mails.)
Then in the infrastructure you declare the implementation. This will be injected in the core classes using `IMailSender`. This way you only have your IMailSender in the Core project with the API you need. In Infrastructure you can use the 3rd party packages to implement the mail services. 

So your `Project.identityServer` should reference Core & Infrastructure